# How do I automate date in SQL query using Python

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have SQL connection and named `db_connection` that I run in weekly basis

```
tran= pd.read_sql('SELECT order_id, p.user_id, p.barcode, title, o.timestamp, amount, p.name, qty FROM transactions t left join orders o on t.order_id = o.id left join products p on t.product_id = p.id where date(o.timestamp)<=\'2017-09-27\' and date(o.timestamp)>=\'2017-09-21\' and p.user_id = \'63165\' ', con=db_connection)

tran2= pd.read_sql('SELECT order_id, p.user_id, p.barcode, title, o.timestamp, amount, p.name, qty FROM transactions t left join orders o on t.order_id = o.id left join products p on t.product_id = p.id where date(o.timestamp)<=\'2017-09-27\' and date(o.timestamp)>=\'2017-09-21\' and p.user_id = \'62345\' ', con=db_connection)

...

tran22= pd.read_sql('SELECT order_id, p.user_id, p.barcode, title, o.timestamp, amount, p.name, qty FROM transactions t left join orders o on t.order_id = o.id left join products p on t.product_id = p.id where date(o.timestamp)<=\'2017-09-27\' and date(o.timestamp)>=\'2017-09-21\' and p.user_id = \'78345\' ', con=db_connection)
```

For example, I want to change all the date to `date(o.timestamp)<=\'2017-10-04\' and date(o.timestamp)>=\'2017-09-28\'`, but it takes time and is prone to mistakes. Is there any solution to make the date is only called once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Python

The dummy solution would be to use a placeholder in order to have a single entry to edit:

```
start = # evaluate or hardcode date
end = # evaluate or hardcode date

tran = pd.read_sql('... where date(o.timestamp)<=\'{END}\' and date(o.timestamp)>=\'{START}\' ...'.format(START=start, END=end), con=db_connection)
...
tran1 = ...
```

### Panda's parameters

```
start = # evaluate or hardcode date
end= # evaluate or hardcode date
tran = pd.read_sql('... where date(o.timestamp)<=%(end)s and date(o.timestamp)>=%(start)s ...',
               con=db_connection, params={"start":start, "end":end})
```

### CURDATE

Using the function [`CURDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) you can parametrize your query. For example, if you run the query every Monday and want the extract the data of the last week (Monday to Sunday), you can set the condition:

```
WHERE DATE(o.timestamp)<=(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) and DATE(o.timestamp)>=(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 8 DAY)
```

This obviously depends on **when** you run the query, but works well if the extraction is automated by a scheduler.

Or, combining it with [`DAYOFWEEK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) we can make it independent from the day of the week it is running (again: considering last Monday-to-Sunday)):

```
WHERE DATE(o.timestamp) >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())+5) DAY) AND DATE(o.timestamp) <= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())-1) DAY)
```

Obviously you'll have to tune the day-offsets according to your needs.

Comment: This is amazing, this is the solution

Comment: which is the one you were looking for?

Comment: Your first solution is not solution that I expected, but the final answer give me idea